# Alternate plugin executions in maven2?

Tags: java, maven-2

In the included configuration, does the "stop-jetty" execution inherit any configuration information from the outer "configuration" element? Will stopPort be 9999 in the "stop-jetty" execution even if I omit it from the stop-jetty execution ? Any documentation references on how this inheritance works would also be awesome.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <contextPath>/foobar</contextPath>
        <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
        <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start-jetty</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <daemon>true</daemon>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>stop-jetty</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <stopKey>foo</stopKey>  <!-- Is this necessary ??? -->
                <stopPort>9999</stopPort> <!-- Is this necessary ??? -->
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
 </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation [here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/examples/execute.html) would suggest that the `/plugin/configuration` is shared by each `execution`, so `/plugin/executions/execution/configuration` effectively inherits.

Since plugins implement the JavaBeans standard, that would suggest that configuring in the execution would also overwrite.